# Hierarchical Grid with MVCContrib

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib

I am trying to come up with the best solution for creating a hierarchical grid in my ASP.NET MVC project.  First, I looked at jqGrid, and found it's "treeGrid" option which is *exactly* what I'm looking for.  However, from what I can tell, jqGrid is not free, and my client is not interested in purchasing a license for it.

To get an idea of what I'm after, the "Tree Grid" demo of jqGrid can be found on this page under "New in version 3.3":
http://www.trirand.com/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

What are my other options for creating a hierarchical grid?  The libraries I'm using so far are ASP.NET MVC, MVCContrib, and jQuery, but I'm open to bringing something else in.  I'm sure I could also roll my own if I have to.  If I do have to roll my own, what approach should I take?

Thanks,

~ Justin

Comment: From the jGrid site: "The jqGrid is released under GPL and MIT licenses. This license policy makes the software available to everyone for free (as in free beer) and you can use it for commercial or open source projects, without any restriction (the freedom above)."

Comment: Then what's with this page with pricing?  
http://www.trirand.net/licensing.aspx

Comment: Can you provide the URL where that quote is from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay thanks to jfar's comment I now understand a little bit more about the jqGrid licensing.  jqGrid is free.  What isn't free is the "jqGrid for ASP.NET" which is a different thing.  So yes I am going to use jqGrid with the Tree Grid option and it should work perfect.  Thanks for the help jfar.

This blog post clarifies the licensing a bit:
http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=479

Comment: Yeah, I was initially confused about the licensing too.